# Plink SSH Host key -> Windows Registry Entry

Tags: windows, rsa, plink

I'm trying to figure out how to make the registry entry that `plink` is making in `windows` when you choose to accept and store a host key... I want to be able to automate this process within `C++`... Has anyone done this? My leads are it gives you the `RSA2 key fingerprint`... Is that whats getting converted to what is being stored in the registry? If so - how? If not - does anyone know if it's possible to automate that entry without having to accept the host key via user interaction?

Rsa2 key fingerprint:

```
f5:11:17:52:e1:bb:5e:12:ad:ce:ef:cd:c2:d1:4d:5a
```

Windows Registry Entry:

```
0x10001,0xc81cb48f929a6f09bab2c27050d53050d9051d3999b552bb1a83f525fea280a1f55424ad4d77c778afdebaf9ff09c99517f77f4da191fde40b65ec867325159663708ffdb6e6661b026611a7b88150279edb166febfcbe122da7d0e53263a068f70e7407a0379a89540f59913512d2ed9138ee09239fc02a2ec50bfbfe2e839a5ab1da505c10e6131bbbc1aa2031a619e8c68cf3ea122e610c62c5ae15db31c2691289568fceae4614cea7b64519a98cc36ee00eb42f957d1fececbf78f8cf1f0587ce0eb09e0863f3526a4bf4e96eeee5f67c4dafc87bd1dc78ee81e651694bad22de954c50df8dde6a3c2e9e982ed448892e7091455249dd720da3cca6e231
```

Any help is much appreciated, I'm not too keen on this portion of the work, I didn't think I'd have to go this deep to auto-accept host keys using `plink` but they really don't want it to be possible to automate this...

Answer (score 0):

The [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-hostkeys) explains why plink itself doesn't offer to automate this process:

> **A.2.9 Is there an option to turn off the annoying host key prompts?**
>   No, there isn't. And there won't be. Even if you write it yourself and send us the patch, we won't accept it.
>   ...
>   Host key checking is your guarantee that the encryption you put on your data at the client end is the same encryption taken off the data at the server end; it's your guarantee that it hasn't been removed and replaced somewhere on the way.

It's important to understand this reasoning before proceeding. However, it goes on to mention two things:

1. the `-hostkey` option, which allows you to specify a known host key on the command-line when running `plink`
2. A Python script for converting OpenSSH `.known_hosts` files into a `.reg` file.

The link to the Python script from the FAQ is broken, but you can find it [in the current git viewer as contrib/kh2reg.py](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=blob;f=contrib/kh2reg.py;hb=HEAD).

The script performs various transforms on the key (probably similar to the difference between standard PEM files and PuTTY's PPK format), and then uses a function `winmungestr` to format it for the registry, which percent-encodes non-printable characters, spaces, and any of  `\*?%~`

You could probably adapt that script to your language and context with a bit of effort.